# CSS popup box is not resetting its data upon closure and the popup is not closing with same button

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, frontend

This code displays a login popup page that closes when the cross button is clicked. However, when I fill in the login or registration information and then close it, the next time I open it, the input box still contains the previous leftover data. How can I reset the popup to always open with a fresh login page?

Also, currently, the popup closes when I click on the cross area in the corner. But I would like it to close when I click the login popup button again. I am new to frontend development and don't know JavaScript. Thank you for your help.

https://codepen.io/Natsuke2/pen/RwYxzpY

HTML-

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <span class="icon-close"><ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon></span>
        <div class="formBox Login">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon></span>
                    <input type="email" required>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="lock-closed"></ion-icon></span>
                    <input type="password" required>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="remeberForgot">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btnPop">Login</button>
                <div class="loginReg">
                    <p>Don't have an account?
                        <a href="#" class="registerLink">Register</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS-

```js
const wrapper=document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const loginLink=document.querySelector('.loginLink');
const registerLink=document.querySelector('.registerLink');
const btnPop=document.querySelector('.btnLogin-popup');
const iconclose=document.querySelector('.icon-close');

registerLink.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.add('active');
});

loginLink.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.remove('active');
});

btnPop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.add('active-popup');
});

iconclose.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    wrapper.classList.remove('active-popup');
});
```

CSS file was long so i didn't send it. Hope you guys understand and help me with it and ask any question i will try to answer.

[image]

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please fix the console error and make it a [mcve] - half the elements in the script do not exist and the CSS is imperative. [edit] and add relevant css

Comment: Thanks for help, let me get on to that.

Answer (score 0):

edit: try using the `value` property for the input fields to reset them, i think this might help:

```
    let email = document.querySelector('input[type="email"]');
    let password = document.querySelector('input[type="password"]');

iconclose.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    email.value = ``;
    password.value = ``;
    wrapper.classList.remove('active-popup');
});
```

for the button I think you just replaced the class name, also use `value` to empty the inputs.

```js
const btnPop = document.querySelector('.btnPop');
btnPop.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    email.value = '';
    password.value = '';
    wrapper.classList.add('active-popup');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into it, but I am sorry for not clarifying enough. Your onblur JS is working fine but I only want to reset the input file when I close the popup, and onblur is erasing when I am clicking anywhere so need help in there. and 2nd snippet is not working because there is already a popup active so when adding the removing function, the button not doing anything,

Comment: https://codepen.io/Natsuke2/pen/RwYxzpY